# Expressing the sum of this geometric series in fraction form?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Geometric series: $6 + 9 + 13.5 + ...$ ($S_{10}$)

As you can see, I need to find the indicated sum.

I used this formula: $S_{n}$ = $\frac {t_{1} (r^{n} - 1)}{r - 1}$, $r \neq 1$ with my:

- $t_{1}$ = $6$
- $r$ = $1.5$

Here's my work:
$S_{10}$ = $\frac {6 (1.5^{10} - 1)}{1.5 - 1}$
$\approx$ $679.98$ (this is right, according to my textbook)

How would I present this in fraction form? I'm totally lost. (the fraction in the textbook: $S_{10} = \frac{174 075}{256}$)

Comment: Write $1.5$ as $3/2$, and clear denominators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the denominator is $1.5-1 = 0.5 = 1/2$ and in the numerator,
$$
1.5^{10} = \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{10} = \frac{3^{10}}{2^{10}}.
$$
Can you take it from here?